# Reading input from file in C

Tags: c, getchar

Okay so I have a file of input that I calculate the amount of words and characters in each line with success.
When I get to the end of the line using the code below it exits the loop and only reads in the first line. How do I move on to the next line of input to continue the program?

EDIT: I must parse each line separately so I cant use EOF

```
while( (c = getchar()) != '\n')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `'\n'` to `EOF`. You're reading until the end of the line when you want to read until the end of the file (EOF is a macro in stdio.h which corresponds to the character at the end of a file).

Disclaimer: I make no claims about the security of the method.

Comment: Of course, this may depend on `c` having been declared with the correct type.

Comment: @Charles correct. I suppose I can only answer on what I can see.

Comment: I understand that. Though I have to parse each line separately.

Comment: That's right. So you could have an if inside to see if `c == '\n'` and act accordingly

Answer (score 3):

'\n' is the line feed (new line)-character, so the loop will terminate when the end of first line is reached. The end of the file is marked by an end-of-file (EOF)-characte. cstdio (or stdio.h), which contains the getchar()-function, has the EOF -constant defined, so just change the while-line to

```
while( (c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `man` page: "reads  the  next  character from stream and returns it as an unsigned char cast to an int, or EOF on end of file or error."  `EOF` is a macro (often -1) for the return of this and related functions that indicates end of file.  You want to check whether this is what you're getting back.  Note that `getc` returns a signed int, but that valid values are unsigned chars cast to ints.  What out if c is a signed char.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the *\n* character is actually a combination of two characters, two bytes:
the 13th byte + the 10th byte. You could try something like,

```
int c2=getchar(),c1;
while(1)
{
  c1=c2;
  c2=getchar();
  if(c1==EOF)
    break;
  if(c1==(char)13 && c2==(char)10)
    break;

  /*use c1 as the input character*/
}
```

this should test if two input characters make the proper couplet (13,10)